# Check whether the checkbox is checked or not in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

My view page:

```
<td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckedStatus, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "cbCheckedStatus7" }, { "name", "cbCheckedStatus" },{"class","onchange"} })  
</td>
<span id="spBlueCheckbox" style="display: none; color: blue;">
```

Jquery:

```
jQuery().ready(function domReady($) {
    if ($('#cbCheckedStatus7').is(':checked')) {
       $('#spBlueCheckbox').show();
    } else {
       $('#spBlueCheckbox').hide();
    }
});
```

if i check the checkbox, no action is taken place, i mean the span tag should be shown, when checkbox is checked. Initially the span is not shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need an event handler for that

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#cbCheckedStatus7').on('change', function() {
        $('#spBlueCheckbox').toggle(this.checked);
    });
});
```

And where did you find that DOM ready handler?

Comment: i have written button click also in that jquery, so 1st used domReady. is this correct or wrong..pls correct me if i am wrong, or what is the best to do that..

Comment: @Govind, I've approved your edit because you said, that code worked, so please accept the answer then.

Comment: @adeneo,  can i use slidedown and slideup here. I tried with slide part , but not working. can you help me in this.

Comment: Yes, you could use slideToggle or `$('#spBlueCheckbox')[this.checked ? 'slideUp' : 'slideDown']();`